# Rspec check method is executed within a block

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec

```
class Foo
  def self.with_context
    # some preprocessing stuff
    yield
    # some postprocessing stuff
  end

  def self.bar
    with_context do
      #some stuff here
    end
  end
end
```

How I can test the Foo.bar method is run inside Foo.with_context ?

It should pass on the above example.

But should fail on the example below:

```
class Foo
  def self.with_context
    # some preprocessing stuff
    yield
    # some postprocessing stuff
  end

  def self.bar
    #some stuff here ( not within the with_context block - FATAL)
  end
end
```

Comment: How you understand or get the taste that `Foo.bar` is running under `Foo.with_contex`? I don't think so. If you have clue please share.